# I would like to create a content type - a static page that can be updated and searched for - that contains multiple content types in a specific order

Tags: entities

The "new content type" would consist of several other content types. 1) Company with multiple fields (text, URL etc.) 2) product class (label, text) 3) product class description (label, text) 4) product (text) 5) Notes (text) to be updated 6) events (text)

There would be 100s of companies, product classes, products, events etc. and I would like to be able to pick one from each content type to make the "new content type"

Comment: I think there's a question missing here.

Comment: Have you had a look at Gatsby, [Tome](https://www.drupal.org/project/tome) or anything else yet? Have you already tried entity references or [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs)? Layout Builder? Views?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your structural needs would be best solved with creating a separate Content Type for each of the combination of data that can meaningfully stand independently on its own.

Company seems to be one, you'll probably need one CT for Companies.

If Product type info always comes together in one whole then it makes sense to create a CT for Product. But if different product info are independent then they should be just fields in your "global", "combination" Content Type.

That last CT should reference a Company through an Entity Reference field and include other text fields for your Product data, or one ER field if Product is an independent CT.

With the help of Inline Entity Form module you can make the Company nodes automatically when creating your global node, if you need that feature, but sort out your structure before you play with this.

You can use Paragraphs module to rearrange references to other CTs in your global CT, so they are different in each node, but it doesn't seem that you need that, or the Layout builder module to override layout for each global node.

You need to be able to pick new combinations from existing data then it makes sense to create Content Types and Taxonomy Vocabularies and terms, and then create the final Content Type that references those CTs and Taxonomies.

There are various options available on how to display the referenced data on the final CT pages.

I don't think you need to learn about Views to solve this problem. But the concept of Content types and Taxonomies is the basis for Drupal and web dev Information Architecture in general. You can find tutorials about those basics online, Drupal specifically so I expect you can easily solve your problem with these instructions after you learn the basics.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't sure if I could do it all with ER fields or if I needed Views.